# Does the azure .net server sdk automatically handle queries from the .net client library event without the corresponding controller actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

If I use a query like this from the client,`List<TodoItem> items = await todoTable.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false).ToListAsync();` the azure .net client sdk translates it into the corresponding URI : `GET /tables/todoitem?$filter=(complete+eq+false) HTTP/1.1.`
However, if my .net backend does not have an corresponding end-point to match this, will the .net server sdk still take care of translating it to the corresponding sql statement and return results ?

The examples I have seen in the documentation seem to have controller actions only for   `// GET tables/TodoItem and  // GET tables/TodoItem/{id}`, so I was wondering how all the other queries would get handled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so I was wondering how all the other queries would get handled?

We can get [The HTTP Table Interfac](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-13-the-http-table-interface/)e from the blog. There are some snippet from the blog.

There are six distinct endpoints that you can use that the SDK exposes to us.

```
Operation   Endpoint    Description
GET /tables/{tablename} QUERY: Read all or a subset of records from the table
GET /tables/{tablename}/{id}    READ: Read a specific ID within the table
POST    /tables/{tablename} INSERT: Inserts a new record into the table
POST    /tables/{tablename}/{id}    UNDELETE: Undeletes a previously deleted record
PATCH   /tables/{tablename} UPDATE: Updates the provided record with new data
DELETE  /tables/{tablename} DELETE: Deletes (or marks for deletion) the provided record
```

> will the .net server sdk still take care of translating it to the corresponding sql statement and return results ?

```
GET /tables/{tablename}
```

With this request, we can send an OData v3 query that includes a subset of the OData v3 specification. Filters, Selects, Skip/Take (paging) and IncludeTotalCount are supported more detail info about URL Conventions (OData Version 3.0) please refer to the [article](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/).

Comment: But are those endpoints automatically defined and 'implemented' - without a matching controller and controller method?

Comment: Yes, it is automatically implemented if you use easy table.

Comment: Thanks @TomSun-MSFT , It makes things a lot clearer now. So if we were to create a .NET backend in azure the 6 operations and endpoints have to be created at the least for each corresponding table in the database. With Easy Tables, those end-points are taken care of by Azure by creating a backend in Nodejs. The only caveat in my experience with using a Nodejs backend is it gets you started fast but then doing things like custom authentication and file syncing etc gets a bit difficult. Thanks for the response again :)

Comment: The endpoints themselves are NOT automatically generated.   Once you have generated the endpoint (by creating a Table Controller in the .NET or Node.js SDK or defining the table in Easy Tables), then the rest of it is taken care of for you.